# DoubleClick for Publishers in Google Play Services cause NullPointerException in 4.2.2

Tags: java, android, admob, google-play-services

From 18 sep, I experienced a lot of crash in my app using ads from Google Play Services only in 4.2.2. There is the report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.webkit.WebSettingsClassic.getDefaultUserAgentForLocale(WebSettingsClassic.java:453)
   at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$Factory.getDefaultUserAgent(WebViewClassic.java:1503)
   at android.webkit.WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent(WebSettings.java:1280)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.g.a(SourceFile:348)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.n.e.a(SourceFile:275)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.b.<init>(SourceFile:296)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.b.<init>(SourceFile:277)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdManagerCreatorImpl.a(SourceFile:36)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.o.onTransact(SourceFile:66)
   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ar$a$a.a()
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ah.b()
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ah.a()
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.au.aM()
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.au.a()
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView.loadAd()
   at ...
```

As you can see the error prompt when try to load a new ad. Anyone that has this error know how to solve it?

[There is a Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/SX9yb3F_PNk) but Google doesn't say anything. The only temporal solution is avoid load ads in Android 4.2.2.

**TEMPORAL SOLUTION**

Kenfoo post a temporal solution based in handle the exception and deactivate the ads during a period of time (5 days):

```
// Setup your default error handler
static Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultExceptionHandler = null;
Context context = your context

final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler =  Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
defaultExceptionHandler = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        for (int nest=0;nest<10 && ex!=null;nest++, ex=ex.getCause()) {
            StackTraceElement[] stelist = ex.getStackTrace();
            for (StackTraceElement ste : stelist) {
                if (ste.getClassName().contains("com.google.android.gms.ads")) {
                    // Save the last time google play ads crashed.
                    // Next time our app starts, we won't activate ads if it happened
                    // within the last N days.
                    SharedPreferences prefs = Settings.getPreferences(context);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putLong("admob_crash_time", System.currentTimeMillis());
                    editor.commit();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (defaultHandler != null) {
            defaultHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
        }
    }
};
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(defaultExceptionHandler);
```

Then in your activity startup where you initialize your ads:

```
Context context = your activity or context;
ViewGroup myadframelayout = your frame or parent layout holding the ad;

SharedPreferences prefs = Settings.getPreferences(context);
long lastAdmobCrashTime = prefs.getLong(admob_crash_time, 0);
long timeSinceLastCrash = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastAdmobCrashTime;
// Last crash >= 5 days ago. Try Admob...
if (timeSinceLastCrash >= 5*24*60*60*1000) {
    try {
        adView = new AdView(context);
        adView.setAdUnitId("YOUR ADMOB AD ID");
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        myadframelayout.addView(adView);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // No revenue from this guy for today... :(
    }
} else {
    // Don't run admob. Do whatever you like here.
    adView = null;
}
```

And in your onResume, onPause, whatnot, if adView is null then don't do anything.

I'll try this patch meanwhile Google doesn't fix it. Also Google finally had responded and they say that a fix will be rolled out in a few days. The 86% crashes belong to Alcatel One Touch 7041X and 7041D.

Comment: I have the same error, it appeared today, from nowhere. All I see is, 95% of the crashes are coming from the device type "ALCATEL ONE TOUCH 7040A (YARISXL)". To be honest, I'm starting to get fed up with Admob, every month there is a random crash that spikes and goes away by itself...